# MySQL - rearrange the order of the indexes in a table?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Is it possible to rearrange the indexes in a MySQL table?

I have a big table with about 20 indexes on it, but as I created them in the course of a few years, they're not logically ordered anymore.
I would like them to have the same order as the columns in the table.
I use Navicat, but I don't see an option to move an index up or down in the list. Is it even possible?

UPDATE:  I just found out that, in PostgreSQL, I can't even change the order of columns, let alone indexes!  And to all those people who say I have to use views, and that the column order is not important: of course it is!  Columns and indexes should be **logically** ordered in the design interface. Most people use GUIs nowadays to edit their tables!

I just can't believe something basic like this is not implemented.  It's 2011, guys!

Comment: 20 indexes?  Do you really need them all?  Every insert, delete, and update now has to write to 21 places.  This is far from free, any indexes you are not getting some value from should be dropped.

Comment: I have some really complex queries with a lot of lookup-ID's referring to other tables... and a lot of different WHERE statements, so yes I need those indexes...

Comment: How long have you been dealing with databases... you can't just "re-order" columns, nor indexes.  Each record and its indexes are written to pages in specific logical order.  They don't write column header info for each entry.  Try to reorder columns on a table that's on a 10 gig table if not larger for a corporation or other business doing large retail volume...  You'd shut down your own business just to be visually "appealing"

Comment: So that's why it's not possible even on a 10k table?  That's just stupid...  I have been dealing with database for over 15 years now, and I find it VERY strange that databases still have the same limitations as 15 years ago...  It's about time someone invents a new kind of database, more virtual, with svn-like qualities where you can roll back a database to every moment in time, with native support for adjancency trees, etc. We're using 30 year old technniques with relational databases!  It's about time for a change... But....that's just my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the order of indexes. It may not matter internally within MySQL, but if you did want to change the order, the only way is to drop and re-create them as required.

Having so many indexes, as @btilly says, might not be the best idea. I don't know what data you have, or the data access patterns that would require indexed access, but it does sound a lot. OTOH, it might just be exactly right. Only someone with access to the DB and has profiled it would know.