# Does the order of KEYs in a CREATE TABLE statement matter?

Tags: mysql, indexing, create-table

*Note: I searched around to see if this question has been asked before. All the existing questions I've been able to find are asking about composite index ordering, or the ordering of columns for queries on an existing table.*

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foobar` (
  `foo_id` int(11),
  `bar_id` int(11),
  KEY `foo_id` (`foo_id`),
  KEY `bar_id` (`bar_id`)
);
```

It has two unrelated indexes on it. If I swap the definition of the two indexes, it might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foobar` (
  `foo_id` int(11),
  `bar_id` int(11),
  KEY `bar_id` (`bar_id`),
  KEY `foo_id` (`foo_id`)
);
```

If I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE foobar` on each of these I can see that there is a difference between the ordering of the `KEY`s for each table. My question is, does the ordering in this specific case matter? I know it would matter if `foo_id` and `bar_id` were used together in a composite index, but here they are not.

If it does indeed matter, is there a way to arbitrarily rearrange the keys once the table has been created? (Something akin to `ALTER TABLE foobar ADD INDEX foo_id (foo_id) AFTER bar_id`, which I'm pretty sure is invalid as written.)

Comment: To rearrange the indexes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5050053

Answer (score 1):

There is no visual representation of the keys, and it would not add any overhead to arrange them in any way. The key-setting function simply adds qualities to existing columns, which can be rearranged.

The only exception I could see to this would be if you went through some IDE (DB Forge, HeidiSQL, SequelPro, etc), which arranged key values to the top of some list they generated. This, however, is on the side of the system which is interpreting it and has nothing to do with the database performance.

Answer (score 0):

No.

All keys are 'equal'.  All are considered when deciding which to use.  The key that has the least 'cost' is used.  ('Cost' is a complicated formula involving the effort to perform the query one way versus another.)

If you are using InnoDB, it is really a good idea to have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

If your table is a "many-to-many" mapping table, here is further advice:
https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

A related topic:  A "composite" index is one that has multiple columns.  (Eg, `INDEX(a,b)`.)  The order of the columns *does* make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use modify in altertable comanad

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY foo_id int AFTER bar_id
```

Comment: I'm not trying to reorder the _columns_, I'm wondering if the order of the _indexes_ matters and how to reorder them if so.

Comment: I could not understand your question. Now i am also searching this.